# At Summit of Apocrypha - Missing Bonless Limbs Book (Ps4)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am at the last  Chapter in the quest 'At the Summit of Apocrypha',  I do not have the boneless limbs book. I have gone back to try to find the book but it is not on the pedestal. I have checked my  Inventory, my house, and all the chest and tradesmen I usually say to.

Is there a way to find the book or is there a way that I can start the quest over without having to go back through all of the quests.

Comment: Skyrim Elders Quest

Comment: If you have finished the quest (i.e., killed Miraak) and the book is still not in your inventory, it could just be a bug, in which case you can cheat in it if you're on pc.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but perhaps someone else will benefit from this.

First, the single most important way to deal with this problem in Skyrim (or, really, in any of the Bethesda ES or Fallout games) is:

1. **Go back to a previous save.**

   In fact, you should be creating saves very (very) often... personally, I'd love to create a save every 5 minutes whether I needed it or not.  But, generally, if this kind of thing happens, then the only thing you can reasonably do is back up a few saves and restart your progress from there.

On the other hand, one of the weird things about these games is that SOMEtimes they 'heal themselves' by resetting positions when the map reloads itself completely, so...

2. **Go off and do some other thing for a long while, then come back.**

   You need to be gone long enough for the cell to completely reset itself, which can take quite some time (both in game and out). But, it's possible that book may be then sitting where it's supposed to be.

Finally, and I'm fairly sure about this, based on what I read at least, you can:

3. **Install a cheat mod to get that book.**
   (Note!  This disables achievements for that save!)

   Since you're on the PS4, your mod selection is pretty limited, however, you do have access to this one:

   [[PS4] Cheat Mod](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2986228)

   This one (amongst other things), provides a doorway in Whiterun to the [Editor Smoke Test Cell](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Test_Cells#Test_Cells).  The trapdoor is behind Warmaiden's in Whiterun.

   Within that cell is the full collection of every book you could possibly need, including:  [On Apocrypha: Boneless Limbs](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Books#Dragonborn)

That... should get you back in business.

Comment: Waiting for an item to appear in your inventory is pointless: your inventory isn't checked regularly against what it *should* contain, unfortunately.

Comment: @Joachim Based on what the OP said, my assumption was that he never found/picked up the book, so it appears that the book might have been catapulted or otherwise moved from its pedestal, and so it might reset. If you are right that he picked it up and somehow lost it, then you are right, waiting will not help.

Comment: "I do not have the book" suggests it's not in the OP's inventory. But yes, you're right, the *cell* might reset - but if the book's already been taken or misplaced, I doubt that particular item will reappear.